# How to Run MsBUILD Command from C# console Application?

Tags: c#, process, msbuild

I am trying to run `msbuild /t:scmclean` from my `C#` console application but failing to. This completely works fine if i run it from my Visual studio command prompt 2017 but fails while executing from my `C#` console application.

My Target folder where I am running this command is : `D:/Git/abc/Build/Tools`, this command internally calls csproj file.

What I have tried:

```
var result = await Cli.Wrap("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe")
                    .WithArguments("/t:scmclean")
                    .WithWorkingDirectory("D:\\git\\abc\\Build\\Tools")
                    .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdOutCO))
                   .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdErrCO))
                    .ExecuteBufferedAsync();
var stdOut1 = stdOutCO.ToString();
var stdErr1 = stdErrCO.ToString();

Console.WriteLine("Build Info:");
Console.WriteLine(stdOut1);
Console.WriteLine(stdErr1);
```

---

This gives an error access denied, however when I check the user using the command

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

it shows as super user.
Another thing that I tried is running after setting the location to my current directory is

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe", "/t:scmclean");
```

this also seems to be failing. Also I need to know how to write the output of a process in console.

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The
> current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `scmclean` is because I couldn't find any information about it. Nevertheless, try the following:

### Option 1 (CliWrap)

**Download/install NuGet packages**:

- `Microsoft.Build.Locator`
- `CliWrap`

**Add the following using directives** (ex: Form1.cs)

- `using System.Diagnostics;`
- `using System.IO;`
- `using Microsoft.Build.Locator;`
- `using CliWrap;`
- `using CliWrap.Buffered;`

Choose one of the options below (ie: Option A, Option B, Option C, Option D, or Option E):

**Option A - ExecuteBufferedAsync**:

```
private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    var result = await Cli.Wrap(msBuildFilename)
            .WithArguments(arguments)
            .WithWorkingDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename))
            .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(result.StandardOutput);
    Console.WriteLine(result.StandardError);
}
```

**Option B - ExecuteAsync**:

```
private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    var stdOutBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    var stdErrBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    var result = await Cli.Wrap(msBuildFilename)
            .WithArguments(arguments)
            .WithWorkingDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename))
            .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdOutBuffer))
            .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdErrBuffer))
            .ExecuteAsync();

    // Access stdout & stderr buffered in-memory as strings
    var stdOut = stdOutBuffer.ToString();
    var stdErr = stdErrBuffer.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(stdOut);
    Console.WriteLine(stdErr);
}
```

**Option C - ExecuteAsync** (Delegate):

**Note**: This option displays real-time output.

```
private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    var result = await Cli.Wrap(msBuildFilename)
           .WithArguments(arguments)
           .WithWorkingDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename))
           .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(delegate (string msg)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(msg);
           }))
           .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(delegate (string msg)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(msg);
           }))
           .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

**Option D - ExecuteAsync** (Action/Delegate):

**Note**: This option displays real-time output.

```
private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    Action<string> handleStdOut = delegate (string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    };

    Action<string> handleStdErr = delegate (string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    };

    var result = await Cli.Wrap(msBuildFilename)
           .WithArguments(arguments)
           .WithWorkingDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename))
           .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(handleStdOut))
           .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(handleStdErr))
           .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

**Option E - ExecuteAsync** (EventStream):

**Note**: This option displays real-time output.

Download/install NuGet package: `System.Reactive.Linq`

Add using directives:

- `using CliWrap.EventStream;`
- `using System.Reactive.Linq;`

```
private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    Command cmd = Cli.Wrap(msBuildFilename)
            .WithArguments(arguments)
            .WithWorkingDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename));
    
    await cmd.Observe().ForEachAsync(cmdEvent =>
    {
        switch (cmdEvent)
        {
            case StartedCommandEvent started:
                Console.WriteLine($"Process started; ID: {started.ProcessId}");
                break;
            case StandardOutputCommandEvent stdOut:
                Console.WriteLine($"{stdOut.Text}");
                break;
            case StandardErrorCommandEvent stdErr:
                Console.WriteLine($"{stdErr.Text}");
                break;
            case ExitedCommandEvent exited:
                Console.WriteLine($"Process exited; Code: {exited.ExitCode}");
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

**(Optional) Add the following method overloads**:

```
public enum VSVersionType
{
    Latest,
    Oldest
}

private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, int vsVersionYear, string arguments = null)
{
    //get Visual Studio instances
    List<VisualStudioInstance> vsInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().OrderBy(x => x.Version).ToList();

    if (vsInstances != null && vsInstances.Count > 0)
    {
        //get MSBuild path
        var msBuildPath = vsInstances.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith(vsVersionYear.ToString())).Select(x => x.MSBuildPath).FirstOrDefault();

        await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, arguments);
    }
}

private async Task RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, VSVersionType vsVersion, string arguments = null)
{
    //get Visual Studio instances
    List<VisualStudioInstance> vsInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().OrderBy(x => x.Version).ToList();

    if (vsInstances != null && vsInstances.Count > 0)
    {
        string msBuildPath = string.Empty;
        if (vsVersion == VSVersionType.Latest)
            msBuildPath = vsInstances[vsInstances.Count - 1].MSBuildPath;
        else if (vsVersion == VSVersionType.Oldest)
            msBuildPath = vsInstances[0].MSBuildPath;

        await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, arguments);
    }
}
```

**Usage 1**:

```
string solutionFilename  = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, 2017);
```

**Usage 2**:

```
string solutionFilename  = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, 2017, "-t:Clean;Compile");
```

**Usage 3**:

```
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, VSVersionType.Oldest);
```

**Usage 4**:

```
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, VSVersionType.Oldest, "-t:Clean;Compile");
```

**Usage 5**:

```
string msBuildPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)), @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin");
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath);
```

**Usage 6**:

```
string msBuildPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)), @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin");
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
await RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, "-t:Clean;Compile"););
```

---

### Option 2 (System.Diagnostics.Process)

**Download/install NuGet package**: `Microsoft.Build.Locator`

**Add the following using directives** (ex: Form1.cs)

- `using System.Diagnostics;`
- `using System.IO;`
- `using Microsoft.Build.Locator;`

```
public enum VSVersionType
{
    Latest,
    Oldest
}

private void RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, int vsVersionYear, string arguments = null)
{
    //get Visual Studio instances
    List<VisualStudioInstance> vsInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().OrderBy(x => x.Version).ToList();

    if (vsInstances != null && vsInstances.Count > 0)
    { 
        //get MSBuild path
        var msBuildPath = vsInstances.Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith(vsVersionYear.ToString())).Select(x => x.MSBuildPath).FirstOrDefault();

        RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, arguments);
    }
}

private void RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, VSVersionType vsVersion, string arguments = null)
{
    //get Visual Studio instances
    List<VisualStudioInstance> vsInstances = MSBuildLocator.QueryVisualStudioInstances().OrderBy(x => x.Version).ToList();

    if (vsInstances != null && vsInstances.Count > 0)
    {
        string msBuildPath = string.Empty;
        if (vsVersion == VSVersionType.Latest)
            msBuildPath = vsInstances[vsInstances.Count - 1].MSBuildPath;
        else if (vsVersion == VSVersionType.Oldest)
            msBuildPath = vsInstances[0].MSBuildPath;

        RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, arguments);
    }
}

private void RunMSBuild(string solutionFilename, string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
{
    //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
    string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

    if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
        throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(msBuildFilename)
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    //set value
    startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arguments))
    {
        if (!arguments.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(solutionFilename)))
        {
            arguments += $" \"{solutionFilename}\"";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        arguments = $" \"{solutionFilename}\"";
    }

    Debug.WriteLine($"arguments: {arguments}");

    //set value
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(solutionFilename);

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();

        p.CancelErrorRead(); //cancel async reading for standard error
        p.CancelOutputRead(); //cancel async reading for standard output
    }
}
```

**Usage 1**:

```
string solutionFilename  = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, 2017);
```

**Usage 2**:

```
string solutionFilename  = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, 2017, "-t:Clean;Compile");
```

**Usage 3**:

```
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, VSVersionType.Oldest);
```

**Usage 4**:

```
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, VSVersionType.Oldest, "-t:Clean;Compile");
```

**Usage 5**:

```
string msBuildPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)), @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin");
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath);
```

**Usage 6**:

```
string msBuildPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)), @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin");
string solutionFilename = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Visual Studio 2017", "Projects", "MyAmazingApp", "MyAmazingApp.sln"));
RunMSBuild(solutionFilename, msBuildPath, "-t:Clean;Compile"););
```

---

**Note**: When using the `Developer Command Prompt`, a batch file ("VsDevCmd.bat") is used to set environment variables. One can see this by:

- Click `Windows Start menu`
- Right-click `Developer Command Prompt...`
- Select `More`
- Select `Open file location`

In the folder that opens:

- Right-click `Developer Command Prompt...` link.
- Select `Properties`
- Select `Shortcut` tab

Look at value of `Target` which shows the batch file that is used to set the environment variables.

---

**Resources**:

- [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0)
- [Find and use a version of MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022)
- [Sort List by Property in the Object in .NET](https://code-maze.com/sort-list-by-object-property-dotnet/)
- [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap#quick-overview)
- [CliWrap — Execute Shell Commands with Extensive Support for Piping](https://dev.to/tyrrrz/cliwrap-execute-shell-commands-with-extensive-support-for-piping-3gm8)
- [Getting lines written to StdOut in 4 conceptually different ways (using CliWrap)](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/k8hsoy/getting_lines_written_to_stdout_in_4_conceptually/)

**Additional Resources**:

- [ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=net-7.0#remarks)
- [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022)
- [MSBuild reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference?view=vs-2022)
- [How to: Clean a build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-clean-a-build?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022)

---

Comment: I would strongly advise using the [Microsoft.Build.Locator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022) package even if you plan to spawn a new process and not embed the build engine.

Comment: @JonathanDodds: I wasn't familiar with [Microsoft.Build.Locator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/find-and-use-msbuild-versions?view=vs-2022). After reviewing the URL provided, I updated the code.

Comment: What i am trying to do is run t:scmclean inside the folder, D:/Git/abc/build/tools with the pass of msbuid.exe , which i should be able to get from the system path set for msbuil.exe from the c# console application. May be i am failing to explain but all i need to do is go to the directory and run t:scmclean , which works fine from command line but not through my c# code

Comment: @madhurima The `/t` (or `/target`) switch specifies a set of targets to  run in the specified project file. When no project file is specified (as in your command line), MSBuild searches the current working directory for a file with a file extension that ends in `proj` (e.g. C# projects use `.csproj`). Is `D:/Git/abc/Build/Tools` guaranteed to contain a `*.*proj` file? Are you getting an error because the file doesn't exist?

Comment: @madhurima: I'm not sure what `t:scmclean` is - I couldn't find any information about it. However, I've updated the post to include usage with NuGet package `CliWrap`. All of the code in the post has been tested.

Comment: @user09938 `/t:scmclean` is running a custom written target named `scmclean` (which I assume is 'scm clean').